# Weighted move rating for AI

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

My AI (for the card game schnapsen) currently calculates every possible way the game could end and then evaluates the percentage of winning for every playable card.
The calculation is done recursively using a tree. If a game could move on in three different ways the percentage of winning on this node would be `mean * (1 - (standardDeviation * f)) * 100` where f is between 0 and 2. When the game can't move on and the AI wins the percentage is 100, when lost 0. I'm including the standard deviation in this formula to prevent the AI from risking too much.

Is there a better formula or way of calculating the next move to maximize the chance of winning? Does including the standard deviation make sense?

Comment: This is a pretty big question on a very big subject. i would suggest asking it at https://ai.stackexchange.com/